# rdlc text box visibility formula

Tags: asp.net, reporting, rdlc

I have an rdlc file that has some text boxes. I have a flag value in my dataset. I want to check that flag if it is 1 then show the text box and if it is 0 then hide the text box.
Any ideas??

```
Fields!ConsentFlag.Value, "DSConsentRelease"
```

This is the field I want to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set the textbox's visibility expression to

```
=iif(Fields!ConsentFlag.Value == 1,true ,false)
```

Comment: if i have to compare string like in case parameter value 'All'  i have to hide that text box .

Comment: =iif(Parameters!PrisonerType.Value = "ALL",true ,false) its works for me also thanks

Answer (score 2):

set the textbox's visibility expression to

`=iif(First(Fields!ConsentFlag.Value, "dsjobsheet")=1,false,true)`

Answer (score -1):

=First(Fields!ConsentFlag.Value, "dsjobsheet")=1 <---- Only replace 1 here your condition.
this code only put Properties->visibility->expression.
Ex. 1 is Visible
    And
    0 is Invisible